# How to apply multiple inputs to an array of function handles in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, function

I have a function handle e.g.

```
x = @(x)[2*x;x^2;x-13;3*x+2]
```

Now I can evaluate all functions for a given points say x(1) giving as a result 2,1,12,5. But I would like to provide it with 4 points like so x(1,2,13,1) and get 2,4,0,5. I know I could write my own function to do this, but this seems fairly basic and I suppose a solution exists, but I don't know how to find it in the documentation.

Comment: Try
x = @(x1,x2,x3,x4)[2*x1;x2^2;x3-13;3*x4+2];
disp(x(1,2,13,1))
     2
     4
     0
     5

Comment: It is documented here: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html#f4-70159

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **solution** can be like this:

```
y = @(x)[2*x(1);x(2)^2;x(3)-13;3*x(4)+2]
```

Then evaluate the function like the following:

```
y([1 2 3 4])
```

Then you will get the following result:

```
[2;4;-10;14]
```

The second solution would be such as mentioned by @Andrei in the comment.